# unable to send POST request to Heroku server using python requests

Tags: python, flask, heroku, python-requests

So I am trying to send a post request with an outside program to my website. it worked well in localhost but now when my server is hosted by Heroku it doesn't. I am using the `requests module`

```
req_id = requests.post('http://admin-monitor.herokuapp.com/computers/verify_login',
                                   json={"MAC address: ": computer_mac_address()})
```

of course, I have a handle for this URL in my server. when I looked into my logs I saw `500 error` for no reason

```
"POST /computers/verify_login HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "-" "python-requests/2.23.0"
```

I doubt that it'll help you but just in case this is the handler for the request

```
app.route('/computers/verify_login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def check_if_user_exists():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        global new_mac_address
        js = request.get_json()
        print(js)
        if js is not None:
            for mac_address in js.values():
                for i in range(len(Todo.query.all())):
                    if mac_address == Todo.query.filter(Todo.id).all()[i].mac_address:
                        print("True!")
                        return str(Todo.query.filter(Todo.id).all()[i].id)
                new_mac_address = mac_address
                print("Not found!")
                return redirect('/computers/add')
        else:
            print("Empty? wtf")
    else:   
        return ""
```

---

```
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103580+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-30 16:42:25,102] ERROR in app: Exception on /computers/verify_login [POST]
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103581+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103584+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1247, in _execute_context
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103584+00:00 app[web.1]: self.dialect.do_execute(
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103585+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 590, in do_execute
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103586+00:00 app[web.1]: cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103586+00:00 app[web.1]: psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch: argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103586+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 3: WHERE todo.id
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103587+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103588+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103588+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103589+00:00 app[web.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103589+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103589+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103590+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103590+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103591+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103591+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103592+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103592+00:00 app[web.1]: reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103593+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103593+00:00 app[web.1]: raise value
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103593+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103594+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.dispatch_request()
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103594+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103595+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103595+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/Server.py", line 115, in check_if_user_exists
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103595+00:00 app[web.1]: if mac_address == Todo.query.filter(Todo.id).all()[i].mac_address:
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103596+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3246, in all
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103596+00:00 app[web.1]: return list(self)
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103597+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3405, in __iter__
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103597+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._execute_and_instances(context)
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103598+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3430, in _execute_and_instances
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103598+00:00 app[web.1]: result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103599+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 984, in execute
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103599+00:00 app[web.1]: return meth(self, multiparams, params)
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103599+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 293, in _execute_on_connection
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103600+00:00 app[web.1]: return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103600+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1097, in _execute_clauseelement
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103601+00:00 app[web.1]: ret = self._execute_context(
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103601+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1287, in _execute_context
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103602+00:00 app[web.1]: self._handle_dbapi_exception(
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103602+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1481, in _handle_dbapi_exception
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103602+00:00 app[web.1]: util.raise_(
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103603+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103603+00:00 app[web.1]: raise exception
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103604+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1247, in _execute_context
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103604+00:00 app[web.1]: self.dialect.do_execute(
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103605+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 590, in do_execute
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103605+00:00 app[web.1]: cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103605+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch) argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103606+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 3: WHERE todo.id
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103606+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103606+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103608+00:00 app[web.1]: [SQL: SELECT todo.id AS todo_id, todo.mac_address AS todo_mac_address, todo.cpu_type AS todo_cpu_type, todo.ram_usage AS todo_ram_usage, todo.running_processes AS todo_running_processes, todo.cpu_usage_procentage AS todo_cpu_usage_procentage, todo.memory_usage_procentage AS todo_memory_usage_procentage
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103608+00:00 app[web.1]: FROM todo
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103609+00:00 app[web.1]: WHERE todo.id]
2020-04-30T16:42:25.103609+00:00 app[web.1]: (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
2020-04-30T16:42:25.105596+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.15.186.69 - - [30/Apr/2020:16:42:25 +0000] "POST /computers/verify_login HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "-" "python-requests/2.23.0"
2020-04-30T16:42:25.318355+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-30 16:42:25,317] ERROR in app: Exception on /computers/1 [POST]
2020-04-30T16:42:25.318357+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-04-30T16:42:25.318358+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
2020-04-30T16:42:25.318358+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2020-04-30T16:42:25.318359+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
2020-04-30T16:42:25.318359+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2020-04-30T16:42:25.318360+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
2020-04-30T16:42:25.318360+00:00 app[web.1]: reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2020-04-30T16:42:25.318360+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
2020-04-30T16:42:25.318361+00:00 app[web.1]: raise value
2020-04-30T16:42:25.318361+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
2020-04-30T16:42:25.318362+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.dispatch_request()
2020-04-30T16:42:25.318362+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
2020-04-30T16:42:25.318362+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2020-04-30T16:42:25.318363+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/Server.py", line 208, in no_one_in_db
2020-04-30T16:42:25.318363+00:00 app[web.1]: print(current_user.allow_to_view_level_2)
2020-04-30T16:42:25.318363+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
2020-04-30T16:42:25.318364+00:00 app[web.1]: return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
2020-04-30T16:42:25.318364+00:00 app[web.1]: AttributeError: 'AnonymousUserMixin' object has no attribute 'allow_to_view_level_2'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the POST request to:

```
req_id = requests.post('http://admin-monitor.herokuapp.com/computers/verify_login',
                               json={"mac_address": computer_mac_address()})
```

Then on the server you have to extract the mac address from the json. So I would replace:

```
for mac_address in js.values():
```

with

```
mac_address = js['mac_address']
```

---

After you posted the error log, I can see that there is database error occurring. There is some data type mismatch, probably with the `id` column in the `todo` table. It should be an integer.

Comment: I don't understand what is the difference between my request and yours? except the name and I if there were more arguments to send I can't use `for mac_address in js.values():`?

Comment: @Patch Are you sending a list of mac addresses? Is that the reason for the loop?

Comment: No for this specific case your code is fine but I am sending another JSON request where there are multiple values. 
anyway it worked with localhost why wouldn't it work now. And how would me changing my code to yours fixes it? it sends error 500

Comment: But it works on localhost that's the thing. I tried url_for still the same income

Comment: @Patch This is a guess, but maybe on Heroku server the json in the POST request is not valid. Could you try a hard coded value instead of using `computer_mac_address()` to check?

Comment: I did same thing

Comment: @Patch It's a database error. Check that the data types, in particular todo.id (should be integer), in the database are correct. The WHERE clause seems incomplete.

Comment: That's it I figured it out it wasn't what I thought at the question

Comment: I did upvote you for the effort but I need to delete the question I can't though... it's a misleading title and I can't really change it

Comment: @Patch No worries. Glad we got there. It was fun tracking down the cause of the error!